# creating models with foreingn keys using django Rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I have the following models

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    address_no = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="No")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Phone Number")
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Parents"
        verbose_name = "Parent"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)


class Child(models.Model):
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    grade = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name="children")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Child"
        verbose_name_plural = "Children"

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return "%s %s" % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
```

So I have different types of users on my system (parents and children). I am implementing them using a relation to the User model because Parents have different fields from Children. (extra: is there a better way to do it?)

I also implemented the serializes for those models in my rest api

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')


class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('url', 'name')


class ParentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent


class ChildSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
```

and used the viewsets to generate the views for the api and the functionality

views.py

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')


class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer



class ParentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Parent.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer


class ChildViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Child.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChildSerializer
```

and set up the urls

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)
router.register(r'parents', views.ParentViewSet)
router.register(r'children', views.ChildViewSet)


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
)
```

So a post in /api/parents would create a new Parent object.But it wont create a user object which is necessary for the Parent model. One way is to do 2 api calls one to /api/users/ a post and create new user and then get the new user's id and use it to post to /api/parents. I would like to avoid this. Is there a way to do this when creating a new parent from within the api. How can I also return the first_name and last_name of the user in the parents list view (api/parents/). Now it only returns the url of the related user but none of its fields

Comment: Imho users should have contacts and graduation details. I guess not every child has a parent. :S The relationships should be maintained in a different table imho. But the current solution might be enough...

Answer (score 0):

> So I have different types of users on my system (parents and
>   children). I am implementing them using a relation to the User model
>   because Parents have different fields from Children. (extra: is there
>   a better way to do it?)

I'd rather use an inverse approach.

```
Person
   Profile
   Contact
   Graduation

ParentChildRelationship
   Parent (Person)
   Child (Person)
```

But I guess that is a matter of taste.

> So a post in /api/parents would create a new Parent object.But it wont
>   create a user object which is necessary for the Parent model. One way
>   is to do 2 api calls one to /api/users/ a post and create new user and
>   then get the new user's id and use it to post to /api/parents. I would
>   like to avoid this. Is there a way to do this when creating a new
>   parent from within the api.

By REST you can always create a new resource for whatever purpose you want. So for example if you want to create resources A and B at once, then you can define a resource called C which can create both at once. It's just the same by reading.

In your current case you don't have to define a new resource. The user is an embedded resource of the parent and the child. So you have to send a representation which contains that embedded resource as well. Typically `{user: {}}` in plain JSON. You probably cannot solve these problems with your current tools. Since I have not a clue about django and python, I cannot help more.